# Three way model transformation guidelines required

Tags: model, transformation

Good Day

I have a scenario where I want to implement three way transformations. I have three different models i.e. UML, uppaal (xml) and verilog (code). Now I want to create real time model transformation among these three models like if I do a change in one model it is reflected in the other. I need guidelines on this implementation.

Best regards.